# Regex for the numbers -25 to 1045 with 4 or less OR statements

Tags: regex

Alright, so I have an assignment where I need to create a regex for a specifics set of numbers. More specifically, the numbers from minus 25 to positive 1045, but with four or less OR operators (|).

I have already tried to create a working regex and working down from there, but I can't find a way to remove any OR operators. Here is the regex I have tried to use:

```
^(-([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])|0|[1-9]\d?\d?|10([0-3][0-9]|4[0-5]))$
```

The regex is, like I said, supposed to work for the `-25` to `1045`, but with less than 4 OR operators `|`, and only those numbers, nothing above or below, and no letters, special characters or whitespace.

This is for an assignment, so it is supposed to work within the 4 OR operators or less restriction.

Comment: If and only if you're fine with negative zero: `^(-?(1?\d|2[0-5])|[1-9]\d?\d?|10([0-3][0-9]|4[0-5]))$`.

Comment: NB: If negative look-ahead is allowed, you don't need any `|` at all.